# fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Service is in unknown state", "status": {}}

Tags: ansible, grafana

This is my ansible playbook and I'm only running into an issue on the final task for starting and enabling Grafana.

```
---
- name: Install Grafana
  hosts: hosts
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: download apt key
    ansible.builtin.apt_key:
      url: https://packages.grafana.com/gpg.key
      state: present
  - name: Add Grafana repo to sources.list 
    ansible.builtin.apt_repository:
      repo: deb https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb stable main
      filename: grafana
      state: present
  - name: Update apt cache and install Grafana
    ansible.builtin.apt:
      name: grafana
      update_cache: yes
  - name: Ensure Grafana is started and enabled
    ansible.builtin.systemd:
      name: grafana-server
      state: started
      enabled: yes
```

This is the error I received:

```
TASK [Ensure Grafana is started and enabled]
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Service is in unknown state", "status": {}}
```

This is also the configuration of my hosts file just in case:

```
[hosts]
localhost
[hosts:vars]
ansible_connection=local
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

I'm pretty much just trying to have it run these two commands I have in a bash script

```
sudo systemctl start grafana-server
sudo systemctl enable grafana-server.service
```

Comment: Journalctl logs ??

Comment: @P.... I ran journalctl and it said no journal files were found

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted out- turns out my system wasn't booted using systemd as init system. So I changed the Ansible module from `ansible.builtin.systemd` to `ansible.builtin.sysvinit`